# Exchange ActiveSync certification error

Tags: exchange, activesync

I have a problem when setting up a MS Outlook 2013 client. I'm trying to connect to the MS Exchange ActiveSync email server. I have installed the certificates for the mail.ourdomain.com, but there's also a problem with autodiscover.ourdomain.com, which doesn't have a certificate.
I can add the account, it says "Congratulations! You have successfully added the account" or something like that, then it asks me to restart Outlook, which I do, and then it displays and error, that it cannot connect to the proxy error, because of the certificate problem.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a SAN certificate and adding the appropriate domains to it, such as mail.domain.com, autodiscover.domain.com, etc.

https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm